# How to add a "Select all" default value to a non-multi-valued parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default-value, selectall

I have a small problem, so I need your help to solve it.

I have a parameter in which I have disabled multi-selection. But I want to add a "select all" default value to it. I don't found how can I do this without multi-values (check-box).

I want to do this because I have a large parameter list of 1000 values, and it's not practical to use check-box in this case.

I have tried to add a specify default value with the same dataset I used for available values, but it doesn't work. This way just return the first value of my query.

Is it possible to do what i want?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Reporting Services 2008 R2 or 2012.

The way to do this is to modify your dataset query that generates the list of available values for the parameter to insert an artificial "All values" option. You then need to modify the query for your main dataset to handle the "All" option, i.e. something like:

```
WHERE Somecolumn = @MyParameter OR @MyParameter = 'All'
```

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9802/Add-quot-Select-All-quot-to-parameter-lists-in-SQL) is to a more detailed example, which is for SSRS 2005 but the principle is the same.